# form control in PHP

Tags: php, forms

I do a form in html for a little website, i want users to subscribe themselves but my PHP control seems to not work and i don't know why! 
My javascript control works but PHP doesn't...
Source:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<form action="InscriptionSucces.html" method="POST" name="Inscription" onSubmit="return verif(this);">
<h2>Identifiants</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Pseudo* : <input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" size="30" /></li>
    <li>Mot de passe* : <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size="30" /></li>
    <li>Veuillez retaper votre mot de passe* : <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" size="30" /></li>
    <li>Adresse mail (valide)* : <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" size="30" value="" />@
        <select name="groupe1" id="groupe1">
            <option value="0">Selectionnez votre adresse...</option>
            <optgroup label="">
                <option value="1">hotmail.fr
                <option value="2">hotmail.com
                <option value="3">gmail.com
                <option value="4">laposte.net
            </optgroup>
         </select>
    </li>
    <li>Veuillez retaper votre adresse mail* : <input type="text" name="mail_verif" id="mail_verif" size="30" value="" />@
        <select name="groupe2" id="groupe2">
                <option value="0">Selectionnez votre adresse...</option>
                <optgroup label="">
                    <option value="1">hotmail.fr
                    <option value="2">hotmail.com
                    <option value="3">gmail.com
                    <option value="4">laposte.net
                </optgroup>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>Date de naissance : <input type="text" name="date_naissance" id="date_naissance" size="30" value="" /> <em>(JJ/MM/AAAA)</em></li> 
    <h5>Les champs signales par * sont obligatoires.</h5>
    <li>
        <td id="envoyer">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="M'inscrire">
        </td>
        <td id="effacer">
            <input type="reset" name="Effacer" >
        </td>
        </td>
    </li>
</form>
```

---

**Here is my javascript which works:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function verif(f)
{
    var regnm = /^[a-zàâäéèêëîïôöùûüç0123456789]+((( |-)[a-zàâäéèêëîïôöùûüç]+$)|$)/i;
    var regmail = /^[a-z]/i;
    if(!regnm.test(f.pseudo.value)) {
        alert("Erreur dans la saisie de votre pseudo");
        return false;
    }
    if(!regnm.test(f.pass.value)) {
        alert("Erreur dans la saisie de votre mot de passe");
        return false;
    }
    if(f.pass.value != f.pass2.value){
        alert("Les mots de passe sont differents");
        return false;
    }
    if(!regmail.test(f.mail.value)){
        alert("adresse mail incorrecte");
        return false;
    }
    if(f.mail.value != f.mail_verif.value){
        alert("adresses mail differentes");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('groupe1').options[0].selected){
            alert("Vous avez oublie de mentionner votre adresse mail");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('groupe1').value != document.getElementById('groupe2').value){
            alert("adresses mail differentes");
        return false;
    }
    return confirm("Vous confirmez l'envoi des donnees?");
} 
</script>
```

---

PHP Code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $errors = array();
    $pseudo=$_POST['pseudo'];
    echo $pseudo; // Pseudo
    if(!isset($pseudo)){
        $errors[] = 'Erreur dans la saisie de votre pseudo';
        return false;
    } elseif($pseudo == '') {
        $errors[] = 'Erreur dans la saisie de votre pseudo';
        return false;
    }
    // Mot de passe
    if(!isset($_POST['pass'])){
        $errors[] = 'Erreur dans la saisie de votre mot de passe';
    } elseif($_POST['pass'] == ''){
        $errors[] = 'Erreur dans la saisie de votre mot de passe';
    }
    // Verif mot de passe
    if($_POST['pass2'] =! $_POST['pass']){
        $errors[] = 'Les mots de passe sont differents';
    } elseif($_POST['mdp_verif'] == ''){
        $errors[] = 'Les mots de passe sont differents';
    } else if(!isset($_POST['mdp_verif'])){
        $errors[] = 'Les mots de passe sont differents';
    }
    // Adresse mail
    if(!isset($_POST['mail'])){
        $errors[] = 'Erreur dans la saisie de votre adresse mail';
    } elseif($_POST['mail'] == ''){
        $errors[] = 'Erreur dans la saisie de votre adresse mail';
    }
    // Verif adresse mail
    if($_POST['mail_verif'] != $_POST['mail']){
        $errors[] = 'Les adresses mail sont differentes';
    } elseif($_POST['mail_verif'] == ''){
        $errors[] = 'Les adresses mail sont differentes';
    } else if(!isset($_POST['mail_verif'])){
        $errors[] = 'Les adresses mail sont differentes';
    }      
    // Compte les erreurs
    if(count($errors) > 0)
    {
        echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;
        for($i=0; $i < count($errors); $i++)
            echo '<li>'. $errors[$i] .'.</li>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<ul>';
    }
}
?>
```

Is it an error in my variables?
with $_POST ?
Thx to help :)

Comment: unable to understand languange of given code

Comment: where are  `<?php` and `?>`tags ? How will php work without them

Comment: what print_r($_POST) shows? Is there any error? Is your html file parsed by php?

Comment: With that vendetta mask I hope you aren't using this for phishing purposes ? Also please define what doesn't work.

Comment: if you did not see taht <?php tags are missing, I would check that your page has a ".php" extension also (and a web server too ;) )

Answer (score 1):

I do this and it works fine. Here i give my edited code for your convenience.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" name="Inscription" onSubmit="return verif(this);">
<h2>Identifiants</h2>
<ul>
<li>Pseudo* : <input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" size="30" /></li>
<li>Mot de passe* : <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size="30" /></li>
<li>Veuillez retaper votre mot de passe* : <input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" size="30" /></li>
<li>Adresse mail (valide)* : <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" size="30" value="" />@
<select name="groupe1" id="groupe1">
<option value="0">Selectionnez votre adresse...
<optgroup label="">
<option value="1">hotmail.fr
<option value="2">hotmail.com
<option value="3">gmail.com
<option value="4">laposte.net
</optgroup>
</select>
</li>
<li>Veuillez retaper votre adresse mail* : <input type="text" name="mail_verif" id="mail_verif" size="30" value="" />@
<select name="groupe2" id="groupe2">
<option value="0">Selectionnez votre adresse...
<optgroup label="">
<option value="1">hotmail.fr
<option value="2">hotmail.com
<option value="3">gmail.com
<option value="4">laposte.net
</optgroup>
</select>
</li>
<li>Date de naissance : <input type="text" name="date_naissance" id="date_naissance" size="30" value="" /> <em>(JJ/MM/AAAA)</em></li> 
<h5>Les champs signales par * sont obligatoires.</h5>                  
<li><td id="envoyer">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="M'inscrire">
</td>
<td id="effacer">
<input type="reset" name="Effacer" >
</td>
</td></li>
</form>
</body>
<!-- Here is my javascript which works
<script type="text/javascript">    

function verif(f)
{

var regnm = /^[a-zàâäéèêëîïôöùûüç0123456789]+((( |-)[a-zàâäéèêëîïôöùûüç]+$)|$)/i;
var regmail = /^[a-z]/i;
if(!regnm.test(f.pseudo.value))
{
alert("Erreur dans la saisie de votre pseudo");
return false;
}
if(!regnm.test(f.pass.value))
{
alert("Erreur dans la saisie de votre mot de passe");
return false;
}
if(f.pass.value != f.pass2.value){
alert("Les mots de passe sont differents");
return false;
}
if(!regmail.test(f.mail.value)){
alert("adresse mail incorrecte");
return false;
}
if(f.mail.value != f.mail_verif.value){
alert("adresses mail differentes");
return false;
}
if (document.getElementById('groupe1').options[0].selected){
alert("Vous avez oublie de mentionner votre adresse mail");
return false;
}
if (document.getElementById('groupe1').value != document.getElementById('groupe2').value){
alert("adresses mail differentes");
return false;
}
return confirm("Vous confirmez l'envoi des donnees?");
} 
</script>
-->
<?php if(!empty($_POST))
{      
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
$errors = array();
$pseudo=$_POST['pseudo'];
echo $pseudo;
if(!isset($pseudo)){
$errors[] = 'Erreur dans la saisie de votre pseudo';
return false;
}
elseif($pseudo == ''){
$errors[] = 'Erreur dans la saisie de votre pseudo';
return false;
}
if(!isset($_POST['pass'])){
$errors[] = 'Erreur dans la saisie de votre mot de passe';
}
elseif($_POST['pass'] == ''){
$errors[] = 'Erreur dans la saisie de votre mot de passe';
}
// Verif mot de passe
if($_POST['pass2'] =! $_POST['pass']){
$errors[] = 'Les mots de passe sont differents';
}
elseif($_POST['mdp_verif'] == ''){
$errors[] = 'Les mots de passe sont differents';
}
else if(!isset($_POST['mdp_verif'])){
$errors[] = 'Les mots de passe sont differents';
}
if(!isset($_POST['mail'])){
$errors[] = 'Erreur dans la saisie de votre adresse mail';
}
elseif($_POST['mail'] == ''){
$errors[] = 'Erreur dans la saisie de votre adresse mail';
}
// Verif adresse mail
if($_POST['mail_verif'] != $_POST['mail']){
$errors[] = 'Les adresses mail sont differentes';
}
elseif($_POST['mail_verif'] == ''){
$errors[] = 'Les adresses mail sont differentes';
}
else if(!isset($_POST['mail_verif'])){
$errors[] = 'Les adresses mail sont differentes';
}      
// Compte les erreurs
if(count($errors) > 0)
{
echo '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;

for($i=0; $i < count($errors); $i++)
echo '<li>'. $errors[$i] .'.</li>' . PHP_EOL;

echo '<ul>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: the problem is that when you submit it send you to the success page :/ even if the form is empty ... And i don't know how to stay on the same page if the control is bad

Comment: you can use if else condition for control this page

Answer (score 0):

First: `PHP` code must be enclosed with `<?php .. ?>` tags.

Second: seems that file you posted here is `*.html` file. It either needs to be `*.php` file or have the webserver configured to parse html files as `.php`

Comment: That depends on how the web servers file handlers are configured. I have rendered php in .html files happily before.

Comment: and put an else with an echo in the end of your code so you can know if the variable is empty.

Comment: sorry i forget to paste the <?php and ?> but there are in my source code ;)

Comment: @NicholasKing: yep. I know that `.html` files can contain php-code(depending on server settings). But I believe that OP's server is not configured in such way(or at least he/she doesn't know about this) because he/she has even missed that `<?php ?>` tags are missed. This was just my assumption

Comment: @konnection: ?? what for? this is not the problem of OP. the problem is that php code is not executed.

Comment: well we are assuming that he forgot the php tags but it may nor be the case , im just giving him another option for debug his code

Comment: what i do not understand is that i give an id and a name "<input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" size="30" /></li>" and my php code does not recognize it when i try "$pseudo=$_POST['pseudo']; echo $pseudo;" it gives me an error of undefined variable :/

Answer (score 0):

In the form tag you use **InscriptionSucces.html**. Instead, you must use the name **InscriptionSucces.php**, and your filename must be **InscriptionSucces.php**.

When you use any PHP code, you must use the correct start and end syntax: `<?php` and `?>`.

Comment: yep i do it but no changes :/ i try a print_r($_POST) at the beginning and at the end of my php and it give "array ()" for both :/ Maybe the server is good configured because i'm at my university

Comment: what i do not understand is that i give an id and a name "<input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" size="30" /></li>" and my php code does not recognize it when i try "$pseudo=$_POST['pseudo']; echo $pseudo;" it gives me an error of undefined variable :/